# Invisible boundary on Synergy client

Tags: synergy

I have a Desktop system (named 'desktop') with 2 monitors attached (one 1680x1050 and another 1920x1080 resolution), running a synergy server. I also have a small ITX machine (named 'tiny') to my right that has a single monitor running at 1280x1024.

The dual-monitor desktop is the synergy "server" and the single monitor system is the "client". Synergy works fine with one exception; if I move the mouse to the client, I can't move my mouse below the top two-thirds of the screen - it just stops. I can grab a mouse attached to the computer, and it moves all the way down, but as soon as I touch the mouse attached to the server, it jumps back to the top of the screen.

Is there an issue with my config?

```
section: screens
    desktop:
    tiny:
end
section: links
    desktop:
            right = tiny
    tiny:
            left = desktop

end
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
    +----------------------------+-----------------------------+
    |                            |                             |
    |                            |                             |
    |                            |                             +-----------------+
    |                            |                             |                 |
    |      desktop 1680x1050     |       desktop 1920x1080     |                 |
    |                            |                             |                 |
    |                            |                             |  tiny 1280x1024 |
    |                            |                             |+---------------+|
    |                            |                             |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
    +----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: As per comments on deleted answer (leaving zero answers in total)  this is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL and the problem can no longer be reproduced. VTC as such.